# Could not import os

Tags: django, bash, import, operating-system

When I try to `import os` in my bash I get:

```
import: unable to open X server ' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/364
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're supposed to type that into the Python REPL, not your shell. As it is you're invoking `import`, the ImageMagick command to take screenshots.

```
$ python
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Jun  4 2010, 18:20:31) 
[GCC 4.4.4 20100503 (Red Hat 4.4.4-2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>>
```